# How to overlay camera capture image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I am replacing the part of image by capture image from camera. i need to perform the activity like this app in my application. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/replace-my-face-funny-girls/id794033892?mt=8

I need a way of how can i take picture from background view with super view image and save the new generated image with merging of both image.
Please suggest me solution.
The simple work i did

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.allowsEditing = NO;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

CGRect overlayRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width,self.imageView.frame.size.height);

    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:overlayRect];
UIImageView *capture_image=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width,self.imageView.frame.size.height)];

capture_image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
[overlayView addSubview:capture_image];
[self.picker setCameraOverlayView:overlayView];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
 }

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
   }
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Please also suggest me if there is any repository working like this approach.

Answer (score 0):

About capturing the image: you might want to look at [FastttCamera](https://github.com/IFTTT/FastttCamera), which allows you to set the camera view to your defined image view and crops the image accordingly.

Good luck!

Comment: unable to open./../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: Manifest.lock: No such file or directory error: 
The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: This is a different issue ;-). 

You could try to do the 'pod install' or update Cocoapods obviously (or downgrade Cocoapods if you are running latest beta which could cause issues), but I can't help you out with pod installs i'm afraid, as I am using Swift myself and succesfully installed it.

Comment: Yes i solved it but it is not what i looking for.i need a view that contain a image in a super view and a camera in background view.